# Frequency of a solution to a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, periodic-functions

[image]

Why is the frequency of $u=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n$sin$(n\pi x/L)$cos($n^2 \pi^2ct/L)$ equal to the coefficent of $t$ with $L>0,c$ constants, i.e

Why is it proportional to $n^2$?

Comment: It would help, in formulating an answer, to know just *what* PDE we are dealing with, i.e. just what PDE $u(x, t)$ solves.  Also, definitions of $L$ and $c$ would be good.  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertLewis Apologies, I have edited the OP to include the question

Comment: thanks so much for the rapid response!  Thinking. . . Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, the instantaneous radian frequency of a harmonic vibration is the time derivative of the argument of the cosine or sine (or complex exponential) describing the vibration. This is the definition for what we mean by frequency. In your case, the time dependence for the $n^\text{th}$ mode is

$$
T_n(t) = \cos(\phi_n(t))
$$
with
$$
\phi_n(t)=n^2\pi^2 ct/L
$$
Now we apply the definition of instantaneous radian frequency:
$$
\omega_n(t) = \phi_n'(t) = n^2\pi^2c/L
$$

This is why the frequency is the coefficient that goes with $t$; it's defined as $\frac{d}{dt}$ of the argument and that operation gives the coefficient in front of any terms linear in $t$. Finally, as to why it is proportional to $n^2$ (instead of $n$ like the normal wave equation): this is not the wave equation, so why would you expect it to have the same properties as it? The extra derivatives in space (compared to the wave equation) causes this "extra" factor of $n$ to appear in the frequency when compared to the wavenumber.